# Change a graph of an accepted conference paper (before submitting the camera-ready version)

Tags: publications, paper-submission

My paper has been accepted to an IEEE conference. But recently, I found some minor errors in my simulation data (using matlab software), and I would like to modify the existing graph before submitting my camera-ready version.

This change will not have major impact on my results as well as the quality of the paper.

The question is, can I simply make this change or do I have to explain this change?

Answer (score 23):

Unlike with a journal, the short review and revision timeline of an IEEE conference (or other EE/CS-style conference) means that it is unusual for there to be any opportunity for additional review.  As a result, there is somewhat more trust placed in authors for making "reasonable changes" for the camera-ready, and it is typically not just permitted but even expected that authors will improve their papers for the camera-ready version.  If nothing else, they are expected to do their best to address the issues raised by the reviewers; fixing problems that they themselves have found is entirely desirable as well.

In short: if your correction does not significantly undermine the basis on which your paper was accepted, you should simply make the change, and everyone will be the better for it.

Answer (score 5):

This actually happen quite often. If it does not change the main conclusion of the paper, it is not a problem. Just make the change and upload the new version as the camera-ready version.